# how to listen button onclick from function.php in wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I make the form with custom template in wordpress. User type the data to a form and click `submit`.

When user click `submit`, Dialog box will have to appear include with button labeled `Home` and then click `home` heading to save the data to database and then heading to `home` page.

So I want to listen `onclick` Home button in dialog box in `function.php` and want to write if condition.

How can i do it?

Comment: why you want to write in functions.php, you can write in js file itself, and for the clarification, do you want to include the script file path in functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Send the onclick call by ajax to your function.php, and proceed by the return of your function.php

Something like this

```
$('#homebutton').click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/function.php',
                    data: {
                        ajax:true,
                        data: {//send data to function.php if needed}
                        },
                    success: function(rsp){
                   //ajax was succesfull and function.php returned rsp
                            console.log(rsp);
                            if(rsp == 'allgood')
                             window.location.href = "/";
                        }
                });
            });
```